# connect last post with first post

Tags: loop, navigation, next-post-link, previous-post-link

next/prev from my first to last and the other way around
cant find a solution for that 
i am using this code for next

```
  <?php next_post_link('%link','<img src="img-location"/>'); ?>
```

and this for prev

```
  <?php previous_post_link('%link','<img src="img-location"/>'); ?>
```

here is the [first post](https://partymmr.com/memes/tiny-family)

Answer (score 0):

You may [install this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loop-post-navigation-links/) and then for the next link, use:

```
<?php c2c_next_or_loop_post_link('%link','<img src="img-location"/>'); ?>
```

and for the previous link use:

```
<?php c2c_previous_or_loop_post_link('%link','<img src="img-location"/>'); ?>
```

That's it. Now the previous link of your first post should be the last post and the next link of your last post should be the first post.

> If you don't want to install any plugin, then you may follow the instructions from [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/89250/110572) to see how it can be done with custom CODE.